# Can I create a stub swagger model definition from a json file

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Is there a tool that lets me generate a Swagger yaml definition model from sample JSON?

I would go in and and edit and clean up the yaml, but would be nice if there was something out there that would stub out the structure of a yaml based on a large or complex sample json object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a Swagger #definition from sample JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277137/how-to-generate-a-swagger-definition-from-sample-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apigee's API Studio that has this feature:

https://apistudios.io

Click on **Insert** menu and then **New Model**. Form a JSON example you can create all of the paths and operations you want.

Comment: API studio is no longer available

Comment: URL should be https://apistudios.io/